# When to use Entity Relationships/Associations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I started to learn symfony2 and I learned the Entity Relationships/Associations with Doctrine.

I wonder when to use it. 
for example, if I got student table and a profession field in it.
now the profession got only 4 options (math,computer science, art, economy).
should I create profession entity and associate it to student? or leave it as field?

Answer (score 2):

Use an entity if the options are dynamic (subject to change).

Otherwise use `constant`.

By the way you can use `constant` in twig too: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html

Answer (score 1):

To improve [Marcel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625172/1361089) I have to add, that options should be subject to change **by the end user**. If profession list should be hardcoded then you can store anything just as array and text field.

Comment: There's a typo: *imporve*.

Comment: I still dont get it.. what the problem to set some function so the end user will add a new option to the array? what the entity Associations gives me? maybe lets say I got users tables and posts tables and I need to associate user to posts is it good example for associations?

Comment: Entity association gives your end users ability to select profession from one global db-persisted list. This list, for example, could be easily extended by adding a new Profession entity to this list by admins or so.

Comment: On the other way if the profession is just matter of text-record - it's even enough to leave it text, so users can enter there what they want, but you cannot control the process totally - users can write any stuff they want. Hardcoded list is intermediate way. Controlled but not extensible.

Comment: So everything depends on your needs. DB Architecture should represent business requirements you have